# Have column with multiple values in powerBI, for use with a slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a column with the following data

```
|  spoon
|  fork
|  fork & spoon
```

I would like to add a slicer to my page that has two options: Spoon, fork.
When Spoon is selected it shows the result for the rows for Spoon and fork & spoon. When Fork is selected it shows the result for the rows for Fork and fork & spoon

Can this be achieved in powerbi?

If not directly, I was thinking that formatting my data like this could help perhaps? Does powerBI have an option to see values divided by semicollons as multiple values?

```
|  Spoon
|  Fork
|  Fork ; Spoon
```

EDIT:
Bit more info on my actual table layout:

```
| Service A |  revenue |  category 1    
| Service B |  revenue |  category 2
| Service C |  revenue |  category 1 & 2
```

Comment: I think you can, but not sure as its been some time since I used it. There is an option that lets you import the data based on the delimiter. Can you check that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be achieved depending on the *result* you want to show for the filtered rows, e.g, a sum, average, count, etc.

I will show you a very simple example of a sum for the filtered rows by using the `SUMX` function available in DAX expressions.

Suppose you have two tables like this:

**MyTable:** Table with the data.

[image]

**SlicerTable:** The table used for creating the slicer.

[image]

Add a slicer to your report using the `SlicerTable[SlicerColumn]` column. Then create a measure called `Result` in the MyTable table with the following expression:

```
Result =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        MyTable,
        [MyColumn] = FIRSTNONBLANK ( SlicerTable[SlicerColumn], 0 )
            || FIND ( FIRSTNONBLANK ( SlicerTable[SlicerColumn], 0 ), [MyColumn], 1, -1 ) > -1
            || NOT ISFILTERED ( SlicerTable[SlicerColumn] )
    ),
    [Value]
)
```

Don't get scared for this DAX expression, it bassicaly check if the MyColumn column contains any of the values selected in the slicer, if there is no selection in the slicer it will sum up all values of `[Value]` column.

Using a matrix or any Power BI visualization with the `MyColumn` column and the `Result` measure, you will get something like this:

[image]

**UPDATE** Alternative support for slicer without a required measure using explicit relationships and adding tables.

I've added two additional tables to your model in order to support your slice requeriment. You will have to create an additional table for supporting many to many relationship and other to get the unique category values.

[image]

**Data**

[image]

When you add a slicer using `CategorySlicer[Slicer]` column, it will automatically filter the `Service` table because of the explicit relationships that exists between the underlying tables.

[image]

If you get stuck creating the required tables, there is a couple of DAX expressions I have in mind to create them.

Also be sure the `Cross Filter Direction` relationship property is set to `Both` in every relationship.

Comment: Awesome answer thanks a lot! But what if I don't want to sum up or count any values but simply filter the right rows? The value I want to display comes from a measure outside of the table applying to the remaining rows. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: @cmplieger, I've seen you updated your question. You can't filter a table that has not a explicit relationship with the slicer table. The only way I know is using a measure as I posted in my answer where I created a measure for summing each `[Value]` value. Could you include sample data of your tables and expected result.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll have to think about custom measures although it might be a bit of a hassle. Can't really share a sample because I have too many tables and measures that interact.

Comment: @cmplieger, I've updated my answer with an alternative solution where measures are not required but you will have to include a couple of tables to your model for supporting the required relationship. Good luck!

Comment: YES! Your second answer works perfectly! Thank you so much. I wish PowerBI would have a native feature for this because adding 3 tables is not exactly elegant, but it works :)